# How to increase or decrease size of Text in Java programmatically? (Text shown on Console and not of JLabel)

Tags: java, text, resize, size, font-size

Hi i want to increase or decrease the size of text programmatically in Java? The text should be increased or decreased programmatically and should work on Console text and not on JLabel.

Comment: That is not going to work. Your application simply outputs text to a console. The Console then decides how to display that data. Font sizes can be adjusted in the settings fo your console.

Comment: But we are given this as a lab task. sir gave us a hint to use Uni Code to resize it.

Comment: "Sir" needs to think of more useful things to teach his students in Lab tasks!